# How to redirect some folders and files to a custom 404 page?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

My webroot has the following folders and files:

```
private.txt
public.txt
private
public
404.html
```

I would like to setup a .htaccess in a way that when a user tries to access
domain.com/private.txt, he will be redirected to domain.com/404.html (with 404 status) but if the user accesses
domain.com/public.txt, no redirection will happen. How can I setup this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect any request contains `private.txt` with `404`  status :

```
ErrorDocument 404   http://your/path/to/404.html
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} private.txt
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404,L]
```

The previous lines will redirect any `URI` contains `private.txt`

If you wanna do that at main root only :

```
ErrorDocument 404   http://your/path/to/404.html
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/private.txt$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [R=404,L]
```